# Amazon S3 and Cloudfront cache, how to clear cache or synchronize their cache

Tags: caching, amazon-s3

I have a cron job that runs every 10 minutes and updates the content-type and x-amz-meta. But since yesterday it seems like after the cron job run, Amazon is not picking up the changes made (refreshing his cache).

I even went and made the changes manually but no change...

When a video is uploaded it has a `application/x-mp4` content-type and the cron job changes it to `video/mp4`.

Although S3 has the right content type `video/mp4` cloudfront shows `application/x-mp4`(old content-type)     ....

The cron job has been working for the last 6 months without a problem.

What is wrong with amazon caching? How can i synchronize the caching?

Comment: Maybe select an answer ;-)

Answer (score 86):

Use Invalidations to clear the cache, you can put the path to the files you want to clear, or simply use wild cards to clear everything.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html#invalidating-objects-api

This can also be done using the API!
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_CreateInvalidation.html

The AWS PHP SDK now has the methods but if you want to use something lighter check out this library:
http://www.subchild.com/2010/09/17/amazon-cloudfront-php-invalidator/

user3305600's solution doesn't work as setting it to zero is the equivalent of Using the Origin Cache Headers.

Comment: This is indeed a better answer

Comment: That library looks to be outdated.

Comment: Hello, I keep seeing comments on threads re: AWS CloudFront invalidations take minutes to complete.  Is this still true in 2023?

Answer (score 65):

As to the actual code

get your CloudFront distribution id

`aws cloudfront list-distributions`

Invalidate all files in the distribution, so CloudFront fetches fresh ones

`aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id=S11A16G5KZMEQD --paths /`

My actual full release script is

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

BUCKET=mysite.com
SOURCE_DIR=dist/

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxxxxxxxx
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxxxxxx
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1


echo "Building production"
if npm run build:prod ; then
   echo "Build Successful"
else
  echo "exiting.."
  exit 1
fi


echo "Removing all files on bucket"
aws s3 rm s3://${BUCKET} --recursive


echo "Attempting to upload site .."
echo "Command:  aws s3  sync $SOURCE_DIR s3://$BUCKET/"
aws s3  sync ${SOURCE_DIR} s3://${BUCKET}/
echo "S3 Upload complete"

echo "Invalidating cloudfrond distribution to get fresh cache"
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id=S11A16G5KZMEQD --paths / --profile=myawsprofile

echo "Deployment complete"
```

## References

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/get-invalidation.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/create-invalidation.html

Comment: Thanks for posting this--I needed to invalidate a distribution to *fully* rid my app of an old, overwritten file version that kept popping up.

Comment: Instead of deleting all files in the bucket first, you can use the `--delete` option of `aws s3 sync` to do that for you.  
i.e. `aws s3 sync ${SOURCE_DIR} s3://${BUCKET}/ --delete`

Comment: Worthwhile to mention here, at path use "/*" invalidate all files in bucket and "/folder_name/*" to invalidate files in folder name. also I think it costs money

Comment: Per the cloudfront pricing page as of today.
"No additional charge for the first 1,000 paths requested for invalidation each month. Thereafter, $0.005 per path requested for invalidation."

Comment: beware that a path of `/` does not invalidate the entire distribution (I'm not exactly sure what it does do); you need to use `/*` to do that

Comment: As a followup, make sure to put the `/*` inside of quotes like this: `"/*"`. This makes the command: `aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id=[ID_HERE]--paths "/*"`. If you don't do that, your command might pick up a list of files or folders on the local machine as the invalidation list! Example after running that command on ubuntu within Github Actions without the quotes showed up like this in the AWS invalidations panel (object paths): `[/lib32, /home, /proc, ...]`. Not what you want!

Answer (score 54):

Here is a manual way to invalidate the cache for all files on CloudFront via AWS

1. Open your CloudFront Distributions list, and click the desired distribution ID (circled in red in screenshot below) you want to clear it's cache.
   [image]
2. Click 'Invalidations' tab (see selected tab highlighted in blue in the screenshot below).
3. Click 'Create invalidation' button (circled in red in the screenshot below)
   [image]
4. Insert `/*` in the *object paths* input in order to clear cache of all files.
5. Click 'Create invalidation' button.
   [image]

Comment: Would this be a temporary change? Would it I need to delete the invalidation? Could I delete it immediately, or would I need to wait a few hours?

Comment: It's a temporary change and you don't need to delete it afterwards. It runs immediately after you create it and clears the entire cache (if you use `/*`). Just saved my day!

Answer (score 23):

S3 is not used for real time development but if you really want to test your freshly deployed website use

```
http://yourdomain.com/index.html?v=2
http://yourdomain.com/init.js?v=2
```

Adding a version parameter in the end will stop using the cached version of the file and the browser will get a fresh copy of the file from the server bucket

Answer (score 12):

Cloudfront will cache a file/object until the cache expiry. By default it is 24 hrs. If you have changed this to a large value, then it takes longer.

If you anytime needs to force clear the cache, use the [invalidation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html). It is charged separately.

Another option is to change the URL (object key), so it fetches the new object always.

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking for a minimal solution that invalidates the cache, this edited version of Dr Manhattan's solution should be sufficient. Note that I'm specifying the root / directory to indicate I want the whole site refreshed.

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<Key>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<Secret>
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1

echo "Invalidating cloudfrond distribution to get fresh cache"
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id=<distributionId> --paths / --profile=<awsprofile>
```

[Region Codes can be found here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#cf_region)

You'll also need to create a profile using the aws cli.
Use the `aws configure --profile` option. Below is an example snippet from Amazon.

```
$ aws configure --profile user2
AWS Access Key ID [None]: AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: je7MtGbClwBF/2Zp9Utk/h3yCo8nvbEXAMPLEKEY
Default region name [None]: us-east-1
Default output format [None]: text
```

Answer (score 1):

(edit: Does not work)As of 2014, You can clear your cache whenever you want, Please go thorough the Documentation or
just go to your distribution settings>Behaviors>Edit

Object Caching Use (*Origin Cache Headers*)
                        **Customize**

Minimum TTL = **0**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html

Comment: Your solution doesn't work as setting it to zero is the equivalent of using the Origin Cache Headers.

Comment: Sorry! Invalidation is the only way to do it! I guess

Answer (score -1):

I believe using * invalidate the entire cache in the distribution. I am trying at the moment, I would update it further

[invalidate request screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3N2K.jpg)

Update:

It worked as expected. Please note that you can invalidate the object you would like by specifying the object path.

Comment: What does invalidate cache actually do? I have it in my pipeline but I always have to hard reload my website to see the changes. I use s3 sync to update website files on S3. I think invalidate cache only clears files from Cloudfront Edge location but not the browsers cache.

Comment: Using * where and how?