# Caching issues on amazon S3

Tags: html, css, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am a beginner at this and I am trying to update HTML and CSS files on Amazon S3. The backend of our website is hosted on Heroku and the front-end is on Amazon S3.

When I update a CSS file, I can see the changes directly in my browser every time I refresh the page. 
BUT, for updates on HTML pages, the changes are not taken into account when I refresh the page in my browser.

Any solution for me? I looked into the caching options but I can't fix it..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question. [Amazon S3 and Cloudfront cache, how to clear cache or synchronize their cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021651/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront-cache-how-to-clear-cache-or-synchronize-their-cache)  Basically you need to clear the cache on S3.