# Google Tag Manager doesn't work with AWS S3 hosted website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

So I have a website hosted on AWS S3 with added SSL protocol https://calc2burn.pl. I have added a Google Tag Manager scripts to the index.html file, but when I'm clicking preview on GTM site I receive message that it [can't connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXIR1.jpg) to website.

After clicking preview the Tag Manager opens up site in a new tab but nothing more happens. I've added my code correctly. I've been searching for solution for last 15 hours. I thought that maybe it's a problem with CloudFare and have modified script as instructed but that didn't help.

The weirdest thing is that once for 100 attempts to reconnect I've received a massage that it has connected to website but the actual Tag Manager account site showed that it's not connected.

Comment: I can't see any GTM code on calc2burn.pl - where did you include it?!

Comment: The first one is added just after head opening tag and second is added just after body opening tag. And I'm 1000% sure that in the in the S3 bucket is correct index.html uploaded file with code in it. I also can't see code when I'm in the code view mode in Chrome.

Comment: Are you using any CloudFront/CloudFlare caching? If it's in S3 and not visible, it is being cached somewhere - clear the Cloudflare cache/invalidate CloudFront cache to make the new file load

Comment: There is something weird with this S3 bucket because just now I have modified header (added some words) and uploaded new index.html file but the website is not showing any changes. And there is no other index.html file in hosted bucket. I don't understand how does it works.

Comment: You are caching items somewhere, most likely at the CDN level - have you cleared your CDN cache? This is a caching problem.

Comment: Well probably I'm using it and that is the issue. Also I have not cleared my CDN cache. I will look how to fix this problem and write here what I have learned.

Comment: If you're using Cloudflare it will most likely have acching at some level - disable it/clear it

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow.   Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so obviously the old version of index.html was still in CDN cache. I had to invalidate all files in the CloudFront distribution. I have found all helpful information on this [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021651/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront-cache-how-to-clear-cache-or-synchronize-their-cache).

Comment: Same thing happened to me.